# Screen area vs Work area rectangle

Tags: winapi, monitor

Have a look at this [API documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917091.aspx)...

Can anyone explain to me the difference between the rcMonitor and rcWork components of the MONITORINFO structure? Although I'm happy with the idea that a window has areas you can't work with (like the caption for instance), I don't really see how this applies to monitors...

All contributions gratefully received...

Martin

Answer (score 21, accepted):

rcMonitor is the total resolution of the display

rcWork is the max area you can use,eg if you <strike>went fullscreen</strike> maximized a window

> The work area is the portion of the
>   screen not obscured by the system
>   taskbar or by application desktop
>   toolbars.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947 - SPI_GETWORKAREA

Comment: Thanks for that - spot on answer that's solved the problem I'm looking at.

Comment: No, if you go _fullscreen_, you fill the rcMonitor RECT. If you _maximize_ a window, you fill the rcWork RECT.

Comment: @d7samurai yea you're correct. Thanks for rectifying