# fullscreen is not always functioning

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day, I have a winform that can set full screen. But sometimes it's not. It is sometimes 3/4 of the screen but sometimes it is full screen. Below is my Code. Anybody knows why it's not always fullscreen....?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None; 
    Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
}
```

When I run it in my pc. Its fine. But when it is in the production. I saw it did not go well. But sometimes it is ok.

By the way, I want my taskbar to be seen. If I set FormWindowState.Maximized, my taskbar would not be seen.

Thank you.

Comment: In what sense does it not working?

Comment: sometimes it is not fullscreen. it only occupy 3/4 of the screen.

Comment: What is the screen size of your PC? And what is the screen size of the production PC?

Comment: production would be 1920 x 1080. and for my pc, I think its lower than that.

Comment: And, does the size in the production PC follows the size in your PC?

Comment: yes, but again. it is sometimes fullscreen, sometimes not.

Comment: I see... Although the production PC screen size is the same (always 1920 x 1080) and it is the same PC, it is sometimes fullscreen ans sometimes are not. Is this correct?

Comment: yes.. sometimes fullscreen and sometimes not.

Comment: Likely, using WorkingArea is not safe to make full screen. As of why it is so with working area, perhaps it is the way its property working internally - may not be accessible for us to know apart from vague MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `WorkingArea` is not the same with Full Screen. `WorkingArea` is relative, not the common way of forcing full screen.

There are a couple of ways to attempt to force the full screen.

One of the most popular way to force fill is by setting [WindowsState to Maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272019/how-to-display-a-windows-form-in-full-screen-on-top-of-the-taskbar) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16618/How-To-Make-a-Windows-Form-App-Truly-Full-Screen-a) - quite popular) combined with setting `TopMost` property to `true`.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Alternatively, less popularly, you could also use [Screen.Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118130/c-sharp-why-wont-a-fullscreen-winform-app-always-cover-the-taskbar) (but may not be absolute too, try to put additional `TopMost = true`)

And finally, you could also using `WorkingArea` with conditional statement. To debug and see what is the `WorkingArea` size in you production PC, you could use [GetWorkingArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a92hss5(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This way, you can debug what is the working area in the production PC and if it is not full screen comparing to the size of the PC, you could force is to full screen. Not so efficient though...

Here is more explanation on [working area vs screen area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041331/screen-area-vs-work-area-rectangle) to help you making decisions.

Edit: with bar to be seen, what I could think of as another way to do this is by Get Screen Size. See:

[How can I get the active screen dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254197/how-can-i-get-the-active-screen-dimensions)

Then you should limit the maximum dimension of your form (y/x-axis) such that you have room for your bar - that is, to be little less than the screen size in one of the axis. Then, on form load or other related events, you could control the position of your WinForm such that you won't block your bar.

See StartupPosition property:

[C# window positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330470/c-sharp-window-positioning)

Comment: I already try that. if I do that, taskbar will not show. I think I should edit may question

Comment: Edit my answer based on the new light of the question

Comment: you got some idea. But I can't test it for production yet. You just have to wait before I can mark it as an answer. Is it ok? Thank you

Comment: That's ok... see if it works. We are here to help each other after all. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` only gets the screen's working area.

I think you need to change it to

```
Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the WindowState to Maximized at run-time:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Or at design-time, using the WindowState property of the form.